# using concat function in sql

Tags: sql, greenplum

Sample data

```
 yearmon
 Jul-2017
 Aug-2017
 Sep-2017
 Jan-2018
 Jul-2018
```

I want to add '15' for yearmon column .

I have tried using concat function but it doesnt work.

Expected

```
  yearmon
 15-Jul-2017
 15-Aug-2017
 15-Sep-2017
 15-Jan-2018
 15-Jul-2018
```

Comment: Please show the query you have tried and explain what doesn't work with it in detail (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: select concat('15+',yearmon) from table; It throws me function concat(string,string) doesnt exist.

Comment: Try this. Select  '15-' || yearmon from table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Standard has an operator for concatenation, which is easy to understand and quick to type. 
You just use the || operator, just like you'd use a + for integers:

```
SELECT '15-' || yearmon AS full_date FROM table;
```

*concat* function is calling || operator internally.
*concat* function will be called as following.

```
SELECT concat ('15-', yearmon) AS full_date FROM table;
SELECT concat_ws ('-', '15', yearmon) AS full_date FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of storing dates as dates and not strings.  For that reason, I would recommend:

```
select to_date('Jul-2017', 'MON-YYYY') + interval '14 day')
```

This results in a value with the appropriate data type.